# VSTS JSON Variable Substitution with Default Release Variables

Tags: json, azure-devops, appsettings, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

**TL; DR**

Is there any way that I can use [JSON variable substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution#json-variable-substitution) with [default Release variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?tabs=batch#default-variables) in VSTS?

**Description**

With VSTS, I can use JSON variable substitution to set values in an `appsettings.json` file at release time.  For example, with an `appsettings.json` file that looks like this:

```
{    
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DM_ADJ": "placeholder",
    "DM_SALES": "placeholder"
  },
  // And so on.  Placeholders get replaced
}
```

I can define a Release variable in VSTS called `ConnectionStrings.DM_ADJ`, and the value I provide there will replace `"placeholder"` in the corresponding JSON line.

Now, I would also like to use some of the default Release variables in my app's configuration.  For example, there are default Release variables called `Release.DefinitionName` and `Release.DefinitionId`.  I thought that I could substitute them into an `appsettings.json` config section like below, but unfortunately, when the Release completes, the `"placeholder"` strings do not get replaced.  Am I missing something?

```
{
  "Release": {
    "DefinitionName": "placeholder",
    "DefinitionId": "placeholder",
  }
  // And so on.  Placeholders do not get replaced
}
```

Comment: Do you means substitute the json variable in **Azure App Service Deploy task**? It only support user definied variable with the name `Release.DefinitionName`.

Comment: The variable `Release.DefinitionName` is the user defined variable which should match your appsettings.json file. (the parameter `Release` and `DefinitionName` are what you showed in your example `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT  No I am using the basic **IIS Web App Deploy** task

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an expected behavior since it excludes the build/release's system definition variables:
[image]

If you want to use the system definition variables in the json file, creating a custom variable and set the value to system defined variable like following instead of using system defined variable directly:
[image]

Comment: Wowww, I feel foolish for missing that note...  I also forgot that you can use the `$()` syntax to use Default variables in a Custom variable.  Thank you very much for pointing out my user error and providing this simple fix!

Comment: A simple fix that is basically a workaround for what looks like a bug/not-implemented yet.*why* can't you use release variables at environment level. I basically need to replicate the *same* variable 'x' times pointed to the release variable. "expected behaviour?" - that's garbage. Could I add a disclaimer to my site "sorry it doesn't work logically,it's expected behaviour though so that's just tough". VSTS release manager is *very* poor compared to the alternatives out there - it's just easy as it's all integrated.

Comment: @GrahamB  I agree; one would definitely expect default variables to work like custom variables out of the box.  Even worse, it looks like [someone else](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/11355081-vsts-release-variables-across-enviroments) has already raised your issue on the VSTS suggestions forum, and it got declined. :/

Answer (score 7):

you need to specify the json file you want to change the values

[image: Release Pipeline]

then you just need to create a variable with the path you want to change.
for example i want to change the property Version

[image: Json File]

so, i need to create a variable with this name:

> **Aplicacao.Version**

[image: Variables]